# Possible to save Mongo data into multiple documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My question is that is it possible to save Mongo data into multiple documents and link them together? I have very large json files so I would like to split them into multiple files and save them in this way each document file size will be smaller?

here is my code which creates really big JSON files and sub arrays, I would like to make each document size smaller as much as possible.

```
 router.post("/request/partial", async (req, res) => {
      const partial = new PartialRequest({
        startingDate: req.body.startingDate,
        requestID: req.body.requestID,
        whoCreated: req.body.whoCreated,
        isNewRequest: true,
        specialRequest: req.body.specialRequest,
        contactInformation: req.body.contactInformation,
        requestInformation: req.body.requestInformation,
        orderInformation: req.body.orderInformation,
        jobSiteInformation: req.body.jobSiteInformation,
 installations : req.body.installations;
      });
    await partial.save().then(result => {
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: 'Handling POST request to /partial',
          result: result
        });
      });
      await Request.findOneAndRemove({
        requestID: req.body.requestID
      }).then(data => {
        return res.status(200).json(data);
      }).catch(error => {
        return res.status(500).json({
          error: error
        })
      })
    })
```

Comment: You want your all data to be stored in single `model` but in step by step . Right ?

Comment: probably yes, what is the better solution? should i split the models? I just want to store data in each mongo document as small as possible..

Comment: You can store data in a single collection in multiple documents.it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can update your document in the for loop.

In my example change the necessary keywords according to your database ,

```
userController.signUp = async function(req,res){
    req.body.installation = [
    {
        "phase":"abc",
        "phase" : "driveOne",
        "text" : "Drive One",
        "textKey" : "",
        "index" : "1.0",
        "subjects":[{
        "id":"1.1.1",
        "text":"test",
        "textKey":"",
        }]
    },


    {
        "phase":"abc",
        "phase" : "driveOne",
        "text" : "Drive One",
        "textKey" : "",
        "index" : "1.0",
        "subjects":[{
        "id":"1.1.1",
        "text":"test",
        "textKey":"",
        }]
    },
    {
        "phase":"abc",
        "phase" : "driveOne",
        "text" : "Drive One",
        "textKey" : "",
        "index" : "1.0",
        "subjects":[{
        "id":"1.1.1",
        "text":"test",
        "textKey":"",
        }]
    },
    {
        "phase":"abc",
        "phase" : "driveOne",
        "text" : "Drive One",
        "textKey" : "",
        "index" : "1.0",
        "subjects":[{
        "id":"1.1.1",
        "text":"test",
        "textKey":"",
        }]
    },

    ]
    //Your DB name instead of userModel
    userModel.findOne({_id: "5d1d9691019db61515450574"})
    .exec(async (err , found)=>{
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }else{
            for(var i = 0; i< req.body.installation.length; i++){
                var hey = req.body.installation[i];
                found.installation[i] = req.body.installation[i];
                console.log("=============================+>" ,found.installation)
                await userModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: found._id} , found, {upsert: true , new: true});

            }
            res.send(found);
        }
    });

}
```

I have tried using 2000 thousand records and it doesn't gives the error.

Comment: Hi, I have modified some part of the code so you can understand... since I have installations array but when I ran this function it does not store installation at all and in the documents installations:[] just empty array

Comment: Updated . Sorry for that mistake . @MuhammadAli

Comment: not exactly what i was looking for... installation is an array and can be very large... so it has to be somehow serialized or divided into chunks to store in the database. storing it into one document makes it too large..

Comment: Thanks for your help though. But i need someway to store into multiple files so it does not create one big document..

Comment: Okk let get back to you with new solution . @MuhammadAli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199058/discussion-between-muhammad-ali-and-pushprajsinh-chudasama).

Comment: any solution yet?

Comment: I posted the answer in your lasted post . Let me also update my answer over here . @MuhammadAli

Comment: I have rolled back the change on this post, for three reasons: (a) "database" is not a proper noun, nor is it camel-cased; (b) there is rarely a need to add line breaks into posts - paragraph breaks are sufficient; (c) chatty material to say that you hope it helps/works/solves the problem are unnecessary. Everyone hopes their help is helpful, and thus it is redundant. Technical writing is an expectation here.